# new version of automake failing

Tags: iptables, automake

I'm trying to build iptables which requires automake as part of the build step.  While I have this working on my machine, a colleague is having trouble.  the configure is failing due to an automake bug as follows:

```
./configure: line 12080: syntax error near unexpected token `libnfnetlink,'
./configure: line 12080: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfnetlink, libnfnetlink >= 1.0,'
```

(automake fails to resolve the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro`...)  The `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is in pkg.m4.  We inserted a line in the top level makefile `aclocal --print-ac-dir`.  This tells us that it points to a directory where pkg.m4 exists, and where the macro seems to be properly defined.  The big difference between our systems seems to be that I have automake 1.11.1, and he has `automake (GNU automake) 1.11.6 (RN  10.10.2 (sic), assuming 1.10.2)`  (I'm not sure what the RN refers to...).  He also has a newer version of autoconf (I have 2.66, he has 2.69).   I noticed that in my colleague's version of the pkg.m4 file, there is a dnl in the middle of the PKG_CHECK_MODULES file, which I do not appear to have, however, it is right before a closing bracket `[] dnl ]`, so I am assuming it is not doing anything.  Does anyone know what might be causing this error, or what I might try next?

(note: I do not want to have to downgrade automake, as this has to work on third party build machines as well).

Thanks,
John

**EDIT:**

In configure.ac, you have the lines:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_LIBIPQ], [test "$enable_libipq" = "yes"])

PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libnfnetlink], [libnfnetlink >= 1.0],
    [nfnetlink=1], [nfnetlink=0])
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_LIBNFNETLINK], [test "$nfnetlink" = 1])
```

The problem is that the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro is not being resolved, so that PKG_CHECK_MODULES ends up in the configure script itself (I suppose that's autoconf then, and not automake - my bad -- still new to all of this).  So in configure, you end up with a line:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libnfnetlink], [libnfnetlink >= 1.0],
```

which bash does not understand, and treats as a syntax error.

Comment: It's a syntax error, possibly an extra bracket somewhere - can you edit your question and add a part of that file near line 12080 ?

Comment: Is the macro present in `aclocal.m4`? Does it appear in the log when you run `aclocal --verbose`?

Comment: The macro appears in pkg.m4, which is in the usr/shared/aclocal directory (and I verified that aclocal points to this directory).  I'll have my colleague run `aclocal --verbose` tomorrow.  Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: It seems we've lost the ability to reproduce the problem (no longer happens on a clean checkout).  Could have been something corrupt in the build directory, but I would be at a loss to explain what.  If we run into it again, I'll update this post.

Comment: I got it today.

Comment: We never did reproduce it with a newer automake.  We were able to reproduce it with older versions of automake (1.10.1), and so our software now has an explicit check for this.    If you have lower than this, then try upgrading.

Comment: My standard recommendation to put a `m4_pattern_forbid([PKG_CHECK_MODULES])dnl` line immediately before the first appearance of `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` would prevent this and cause `autoreconf` to fail when it cannot successfully run `aclocal`. Or are you avoiding `autoreconf` and calling `aclocal` by yourself and it fails due to you having missed something there?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my compilation env.

In my case, it helped to downgrade `pkg-config` to `version 0.24`, and `libtool` to `version 2.4.2`